# gorm: can't preload field Repository for main.Application

Tags: go, go-gorm

When hitting this endpoint I get the following error, followed by a process exit:

```
2023/11/16 20:13:38 can't preload field Repository for main.Application
exit status 1
```

I'm trying to preload Repository so I can access the Url of the repository on the frontend

routehandler:

```
func ApplicationsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var applications []Application
    var queryError = database.Model(Application{}).
        Preload("Repository").
        Find(&applications).
        Error

    if queryError != nil {
        log.Fatalln(queryError)
    }

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(applications)
}
```

structs:

```
type Application struct {
    ID         int64                 `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name       string                `json:"name"`
    Repository ApplicationRepository `json:"repository_id" gorm:"ForeignKey:repository_id"`
    Username   string                `json:"username"`
    IpAddress  string                `json:"ip_addreess"`
}

type ApplicationRepository struct {
    ID  int64  `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Url string `json:"url"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add `ApplicationID` in `ApplicationRepository` for the relations.

```
type Application struct {
    ID         int64                 `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name       string                `json:"name"`
    Repository ApplicationRepository `json:"repository"`
    Username   string                `json:"username"`
    IpAddress  string                `json:"ip_addreess"`
}

type ApplicationRepository struct {
    ID  int64  `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Url string `json:"url"`
    ApplicationID `json:"application_id"`
}
```